# Check for foreignkey relations

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have an object instance of the following class

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, I want to change the 'disabled' value to True, but only if no other object has the Keyword in a ForeignKey or ManyToMany relation.

When deleting an object, all objects that has it as a foreign key relation is deleted too. When deleting objects from the admin interface, it is able to display what other objects will be deleted this way. So obviously, there is a way to detect if objects rely on each other in this way.

How would I go about making such a check myself? I realize that I could do something like this

```
k = Keyword.objects.get(pk=1)
if len(k.whatever_set.all()) == 0:
    k.disabled = True
    k.save()
```

The problem is that many objects rely on this Keyword class, so it would be messy.

Comment: Please don't use that sample code. It retrieves all whatevers from the database and discards them. Use `k.whatever_set.exists()` to just check that there is at least one.

Comment: alright. But is this the only way to do it then? To check by the names of the objects?